# how to disable quick access popup(Open all Menu) for a profile user except admin?

Tags: vtiger

I need that a sales profile user can not see the other Main menu  except sales and analytics while other user can see all the main mainu list.
there is a shortcut image(small computer) with tool tip name "open all menu" . when we click on it it opens all the menus with its submneus . that i have to disable for same profile user while other users can see this image.

Answer (score 0):

You go to Setting > Profiles then:
Manage user-specific modules access to different Roles